# Filtering through a list of numbers

Tags: scheme, racket

This is my function for curry:

```
(define (curry g)
  (lambda(x)
    (lambda(y)
      (g x y))))
```

I'm trying to produce a list of numbers not equal to 1 using the curry function.

What I have so far is:

```
(define filter-numbers ((curry filter)
                       ((curry equal?) 1)))
```

But it only produces the list of numbers equal to 1.

ex. (filter-numbers (list 1 2 3)) -> (list 1)

I want to get (list 2 3) but have no idea how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Any reason why you are defining your own curry function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - is the right approach in Racket, using the built-in [`curry`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29) and [`filter-not`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-not%29%29) procedures:

```
(define filter-numbers 
  (curry filter-not (curry equal? 1)))
```

Alternatively, using your implementation of `curry`:

```
(define filter-numbers 
  ((curry filter-not)
   ((curry equal?) 1)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(filter-numbers '(1 2 3 4 5 1 7 1))
=> '(2 3 4 5 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter function retains elements which *satisfy* the test. You have to negate your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function my-compose as follows:

```
(define (my-compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

and with your curry function:

```
(define (curry g)
  (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (g x y))))
```

You can create a filter function (without using filter-not)

```
(define (filter-numbers lst) 
  (filter (my-compose not ( (curry  =) 1)) lst))


(filter-numbers (list 1 2 1 1 3 4 2 ))  => (list 2 3 4 2)
```